# How do I log from other classes than the controller in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net, logging, asp.net-core

ASP.NET Core has built-in support for logging, but the documentation states that logging should be done by requesting an `ILogger` via dependency injection, i.e. by adding it as an argument to the `Controller` constructor.

Polluting method signatures or constructors throughout my code with `ILogger` arguments feels like the wrong solution for this cross-cutting concern.  In Android the `Log` class is static, making it trivial to log from any part of the code.

What would be a good way to do logging from other places than the controller?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Sharing Bjorn Reppens concerns regarding the accepted answer, and taking Cyprien Autexiers comments into account, I ended up with this (boiled down) solution for "built in DI" without "polluting constructors"  in "other classes than the controller" in .NET Core 3.1

Factory:

```
public class Runtime
{
    public static ILogger<T> GetLogger<T>()
    {
        using var serviceScope = host.Services.CreateScope();
        var services = serviceScope.ServiceProvider;
        return services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<T>>();
    }

    static IHost host;

    CancellationTokenSource CancellationSource { get; } = new CancellationTokenSource();

    Task hostTask;

    public void Start()
    {
        var hostBuilder = Host.CreateDefaultBuilder();
        hostBuilder.ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>());
        host = hostBuilder.Build();
        hostTask = host.RunAsync(CancellationSource.Token);
    }
}
```

Client:

```
public class OtherClass
{
    ILogger Logger { get; }

    public OtherClass() => Logger = Runtime.GetLogger<OtherClass>();
}
```

For further abstraction:

```
public abstract class LoggerBase<T>
{   
    protected ILogger Logger => RunTime.GetLogger<T>();
}
```

e.g.

```
public class OtherClass : LoggerBase<OtherClass>
{
    public OtherClass() => Logger.LogInformation("Instantiated");
}
```

Answer (score 33):

Regarding using logging in any component:

> Adding logging to a component in your application is done by requesting either an `ILoggerFactory` or an `ILogger<T>` via Dependency Injection. If an `ILoggerFactory` is requested, a logger must be created using its `CreateLogger` method.

If your `CustomClass` is a data container (DTO class), it should not know about logging, but just contain data.

For other classes with names like "Service" , "Provider", "Handler" and so on, the best practices is to resolve instances using dependency injection. In general, you should use DI wherever it is possible, as it’s a technique for achieving loose coupling between objects and their collaborators or dependencies. For more information, the following question might be interesting: [Should I use Dependency Injection or static factories?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/190120/should-i-use-dependency-injection-or-static-factories)

So simply add `ILogger<CustomClass>` to its constructor (actually the same way, as you do for controllers), as .NET Core supports only constructor injection by default:

```
public class CustomClass
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public CustomClass(ILogger<CustomClass> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }
}
```

---

ASP.NET Core’s built-in dependency injection container will automatically resolved transient dependencies. So if your controller has class `A` as a dependency that uses class `B` where you want to log something, your code can be something like this:

```
public class MyController
{
    public MyController(ClassA classA)
    { ... }
}

public class ClassA
{
    public ClassA(ClassB classB)
    { ... }
}

public class ClassB
{
    private readonly ILogger _logger;

    public ClassB(ILogger<ClassB> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void DoSomethingWithLogging()
    {
        // use _logger
    }
}
```

Note that you also need to register the dependencies in `Startup` using `IServiceCollection.Add…` methods:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // ...

    services.AddTransient<ClassB>();
    services.AddTransient<ClassA>();
}
```

---

Built-in logging support means that .NET Core out of the box knows about and is using built-in abstractions for logging. This is mainly done by  `ILoggerFactory` and  `ILoggerProvider` interfaces.

```
/// <summary>
/// Represents a type used to configure the logging system and create instances of <see cref="ILogger"/> from
/// the registered <see cref="ILoggerProvider"/>s.
/// </summary>
public interface ILoggerFactory : IDisposable

// <summary>
/// Represents a type that can create instances of <see cref="ILogger"/>.
/// </summary>
public interface ILoggerProvider : IDisposable
```

Using your own `ILoggerProvider` implementation, you can add your own logger that can do whatever you want. You can check the [NLog](https://github.com/NLog/NLog.Extensions.Logging/blob/master/src/NLog.Extensions.Logging/NLogLoggerProvider.cs) logger implementation as working example.

And thanks to `ILoggerFactory`, you can simply configure your Logger for project-specific purposes:

> To configure logging in your ASP.NET Core application, you should resolve `ILoggerFactory` in the `Configure` method of your `Startup` class. ASP.NET Core will automatically provide an instance of `ILoggerFactory` using Dependency Injection when you add a parameter of this type to the `Configure` method.

Comment: If I understand correctly this suggestion forces you to add an ILogger argument to every single constructor of every single class that uses some other class that uses something that in the end uses a class that sometimes occasionally wants to log something.  And then assigning the logger to a field in each of those classes all the way down the stack to the   class that actually uses the logger?  A lot of classes will depend on logging even if they never do any logging.  Doesn't this have a rather negative affect on readability?

Comment: you described non DI approach, when you need to pass in dependencies throw all "class chain" to target class. With DI you need to add logging only to that classes, that will use it: with DI you are not calling ctor's directly, reflection is doing this.

Comment: look on https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/dependency-injection.html and http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/asp.net-core/1949/dependency-injection#t=201608210934061701309

Comment: Thanks.  But the critical part of the puzzle is still missing.  How can I make dependencies become injected into classes that I am currently instantiating on my own?   This solution only seems to work for the special case of type Controller which is magically created by the framework?

Comment: have updated post, but you need to read documentation more carefully...

Comment: What you see as polluting the constructors is actually needed to ensure that each type use a different logger and allow proper filter through logging filters. Android Log cannot be filter unless you pollute your string manually with prefixes. In addition you can't replace the implementation nor can you mock it. In addition in a DI world you should not be building the dependency graph. I your controller requires a service It should just ask for that service not for it's dependencies. You should never give an ILogger created for one type to another type. It would defeat its purpose.

Answer (score 6):

This article indicates that you should use DI to inject your logger in all classes that need it:
https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/fundamentals/logging.html

> "This technique is not limited to controllers, but can be utilized by any of your application services that utilize Dependency Injection."

On the other hand, here is an article (Microsoft sponsored) that mentions a global static reference approach:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/mt694089.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> "As you may notice, this requires access to the same logger factory instance on which the providers were previously configured. And while it’s conceivable you could pass the logger factory instance into every class from which you want to perform logging, it would quickly become a hassle that would beg for refactoring.
>
> The solution is to save a single static ILoggerFactory as a static property that’s available for all classes when instantiating their object’s specific ILoggger instance. For example, consider adding an ApplicationLogging static class that includes a static ILoggerFactory instance:"

Not trying to stoke the Static vs. DI vs. Service Locator: Pattern or Anti-pattern debates, I personally find common cross-cutting concerns such as logging and configuration to be candidates for this latter approach, but have used both in the past.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change things around. Say if I had this code:

```
try
{
    WeatherForecast weatherForecast = await _weatherForecastService.GetWeatherAsync(city);
    return Ok(weatherForecast);
}
catch (MyException e)
{
    return await new HttpResponseHelper(--> CAN'T INSTANTIATE LOGGER<T> HERE <---).ReturnHttpResponseFailure(e.StatusCode, e.Message);
}
```

The trick is to pass HttpResponseHelper in as an argument in the Constructor:

```
public WeatherForecastController(IWeatherForecastService weatherForecastService, IHttpResponseHelper httpResponseHelper)
{
    _weatherForecastService = weatherForecastService;
    _httpResponseHelper = httpResponseHelper;
}
```

I wire this up in the Program/Startup Config:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<IWeatherForecastService, WeatherForecastService>();

builder.Services.AddScoped<IHttpResponseHelper, HttpResponseHelper>();
```

Now the HttpResponseHelper has been already setup to use in the class:

```
catch (MyException e)
{
    return await _httpResponseHelper.ReturnHttpResponseFailure(e.StatusCode, e.Message);
}
```